# Why Tom didn't get food?

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

There were two friends, Joy and Tom. Tom was oversmart and always thought he was brilliant and smarter than anyone else, especially Joy.

Once Tom and Joy went for a trip around the world and got lost in an Arabian desert during their journey. They walked and walked and walked over the sand for two days and reached no where. They were suffering from hunger and thirst and even couldn't find anything to drink or an oasis.

On the third day morning they reached a mosque. They saw that there are people inside that mosque and decided to go inside the mosque and ask for food and drink.

Inside the mosque, they met the Imam (mosque leader). He asked them, "Who are you gentlemen?". 
Then Joy replied: "I am Joy".
Before replying, Tom thought for a while. He thought that if he said a 'Muslim' name he may get special consideration and get more food and water. And Joy is a fool and he may get kicked out. Then he replied: "I am Abdullah, and we got lost in the desert for over three days. We need help".

The Imam then called his assistant and asked him to arrange food and drinks for one man in the dining hall.

Then Tom thought Joy was going to be kicked out and one he is going to get food and all.

Once the food was ready, the Imam came and invited only 'Joy' to have food. Seeing this, Tom felt like his head was rotating and was about to cry. At that time the Imam came and said something to him.

1) Why did the Imam give food and all to Joy only?

2) What did the Imam say to Tom (fake Abdullah) in the end?

---

*Note: Request to place answers in spoiler tags.*

Comment: Extremely subjective valid answers could range from It is Ramadan to the Imam found him to be a liar to the Imam had only food for one person to Imam liked the name Joy whatever...

Comment: But there will be only one answer that will fit more logically.

Comment: @skv: If consider what you said, theme there will be multiple answers for almost all the puzzles or riddles and anyone can claim there answer is right with their own silly explanations.

Comment: Please read http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/why-are-questions-off-topic-if-they-invite-answers-which-are-not-demonstrably-co

Comment: nonsense trivia: Joy is a dude, "Who are you gentlemen?" , "arrange food and drinks for one man"

Comment: I have never heard of "Joy" being a name for a male...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i think there are certain days that Muslims are not allowed to eat or drink, i think that's why Tom didn't receive any food since that he pretended as a Muslim. Maybe the Imam said to Tom to kneel or pray with the other Muslims

Comment: As far as I know, in life-threatening situations an exception is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

> It was Ramadan, and Abdullah is a distinctly Islamic name. The Imam assumed that Tom was Islamic and hence was fasting.

Answer (score 2):

This was similar to a story which i read earlier.It is same, but it seems to be converted into a puzzle..

> Muslims keeps fast in day time and as it was Morning time and Ramadan days fast (Roza) is going on.
> Answers: 
>  (1) As Joy is non muslims and hungry,only he got Food.  
> (2) Told fake Abdullah to wait for food and water to evening when fast (Rozah)ends.